# Can a Dapp buy or sell (usdtz or tzbtc) from dexter?

Tags: smartpy, dex

Looking for a way for a dapp to buy tzBTC automatically after receiving tez from a baker.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "dapp" as in "front-end dapp", it is technically possible but highly dangerous and cumbersome: the exchange between XTZ and tzBTC requires signing a transaction so you would have to store a private key into the interface and keep it open at all time (suffice to say, you shouldn't do it).

What is possible is to do it server-side with a script that listens to changes of balance for a certain address or runs at fixed intervals and when a credit of XTZ is detected, the script can use a private key that is securely stored to sign a transaction and buy tzBTC from Dexter.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was thinking if it is possible for a "back-end" dapp ie the dapp sends tez (via  entry point )to dexter and dexter simply sends back tzBTC.  Since signing is required i dont think my idea will work.

Comment: There are different solutions you can use if you want to sign transactions from the back-end, for example, the `@taquito/signer` package has a function called `InMemorySigner` that you can set up with a private key and that will be used in all the subsequent operations :)